# Can't get data from remote server by proxy engine

Tags: extjs, proxy, connection, extjs4.1

I met another strange issue in my work with ExtJS. I get JSON data from my folder myapp/data/users.json but when I change it to URL address pointed to remote server (http://myserver/users.json or .../getusers.php) I get none json data.

My code:

```
Ext.define('APP.store.Users', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'APP.model.User',
    autoLoad : true,

    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'http://myserver.com/users.json', 
        //api : {
        //    //read : 'data/users.json' // it works OK
        //},

        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        },
        extraParams: {
            action: 'someaction',
            name: 'user'
        },
        noCache: false,             
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'users',
            successProperty : 'success',
            getResponseData : function(r) {
                console.log("RESPONSE in reader: ", r);
            }
        },
        afterRequest : function(request, success) {
            console.log(request, success); // success: either true or false
        },
```

....

I have installed Apache server to use ExtJS and can load data for localhost/users.json with succ. I thought the problem can make my system. But I checked both for Windows XP and Windows 7 with turned firewall off. It didn't help.

Firebug -> Network shows Http code 200 for the remote address but in respone tab is no data (in this case json structue).

```
Request headers from Firebug:
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-He...    x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    myserver.com // WAS CHANGED
Origin  http://localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

I have no idea what can be wrogn. All seems to be ok.

Thank you for any hint.

Bogus

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about my answer, but AJAX does not support cross-domain requests (and by referring to myserver.com, it is considered cross domain). You'd need to use `jsonp` for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the docs:

> AjaxProxy cannot be used to retrieve data from other domains. If your
>   application is running on http://domainA.com it cannot load data from
>   http://domainB.com because browsers have a built-in security policy
>   that prohibits domains talking to each other via AJAX.
>
> If you need to read data from another domain and can't set up a proxy
>   server (some software that runs on your own domain's web server and
>   transparently forwards requests to http://domainB.com, making it look
>   like they actually came from http://domainA.com), you can use
>   Ext.data.proxy.JsonP and a technique known as JSON-P (JSON with
>   Padding), which can help you get around the problem so long as the
>   server on http://domainB.com is set up to support JSON-P responses.
>   See JsonPProxy's introduction docs for more details.

Comment: As I understand correct. Developing on localhost and when project is ready deploy on production server?

Comment: Don't hard code the server. You can use relative paths with AJAX. Then when you switch servers it all works out.